# Prerendering Vue? Nuxt.js or plugin, what is better for existing website

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have webiste which is available in the internet. Front is written in Vue.js and CMS is created using Laravel (PHP). These are separate applications.
Unfortunatelly Google dosen't see the page because of lack of SEO (yeah! Vue). The website is big, has a lot of routes, fetches data from API ex. for a blog.
Here is my question. What is a better solution? Move website to Nuxt.js or use some fancy plugin like https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin and fetch data from API. 
I'll be gratefull for any tips!

Comment: [pre-rendering](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) is the correct approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes of course, but  pre-rendering I can achive using nuxt (SSR) or plugins. What is better if I have ready huge website?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@prerenderer/renderer-puppeteer` if: You're prerendering up to a couple hundred pages and want accurate results.

Use `@prerenderer/renderer-jsdom` if: You need to prerender thousands upon thousands of pages, but quality isn't all that important, and you're willing to work around issues for more advanced cases. (Programmatic SVG support, etc.)

Comment: Hmm in docs is note 'This package is unstable and still under active development. Use at your own risk.'? 
I can't find any information about fetching data from API.